# Как сохранить данные в textarea чтобы после перезагрузки они сохранились

Tags: php, ajax

```
    <?php
     if ($_POST) {
      $string = serialize($_POST);
      $name = $_POST['name'];}?>    
    <textarea name="cont" class='item-name'>
      <?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ echo $_POST['name'];} ?>
    </textarea>
```

С помощью данного кода вывожу в textarea данные с iputa, но если перезагрузить страницу данные исчезают. Как сохранить данные в txt файл, чтобы после **перезагрузки страницы** их можно было вывести в textarea?

Comment: Не совсем понятно про файл. Опишите подробнее, что должно происходить после загрузки страницы, в момент нажатия кнопки, обработка полученного на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

[file_put_contents — Пишет данные в файл](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php)

[file_get_contents — Читает содержимое файла в строку](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)

Пишите в файл `file_put_contents($file, $str);`

Получаете из файла `$str = file_get_contents($file);`